# Error with POST ajax during image upload with dropzone

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, laravel, dropzone.js

I have a form,where I included the dropzone.js. The plugin its working till preview image,after I get a POST error:`500 (Internal Server Error)` on `dropzone.js:1386`

```
Dropzone.prototype.submitRequest = function(xhr, formData, files) {
      return xhr.send(formData);<--here
    };
```

My view:

```js
Dropzone.options.images = false;
 $("#images").dropzone({ 
  url: "{{url('/')}}/ajax-uploadvehicleimage",
  paramName: "file",
  maxFiles: 10,
    maxfilesexceeded: function(file) {
        this.removeFile(file);
        alert('you no have more picture avaible! Pay for more here');
    },
     error: function(file, response) {
        if($.type(response) === "string")
            var message = response; //dropzone sends it's own error messages in string
        else
            var message = response.message;
      
        file.previewElement.classList.add("dz-error");
        _ref = file.previewElement.querySelectorAll("[data-dz-errormessage]");
        _results = [];
        for (_i = 0, _len = _ref.length; _i < _len; _i++) {
            node = _ref[_i];
            _results.push(node.textContent = message);
        }

        return _results;
    },
     success: function(file,done) {
       alert(done);
    }
});
```

```html
<div id="images" class="dropzone">
 </div>
```

The route:

```
Route::post('/ajax-uploadvehicleimage','VehicleAddController@uploadimg');
```

The controller:

```
public function uploadimg(){
         if (Request::hasFile('file'))
    {
        //houston we have a file!
        $file = Request::file('file');

        //move it to our public folder and rename it to $name
        Request::file('file')->move('images', 'insert_file_name.'.$file->getClientOriginalExtension());
        echo 'file uploaded!';
        var_dump($file);
    }else{
        echo 'no file, no bueno';
    }
    }
```

Can explain me whats the problem,and how can I change it or sample? I read a lot of topic about that but no one is releasd!

EDIT:
Laravel.log:

```
[2017-01-13 07:55:38] local.ERROR: exception 'Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalErrorException' with message 'Can't use function return value in write context' in E:\bitnami\apache2\htdocs\vehicle\app\Http\Controllers\VehicleAddController.php:103
Stack trace:
#0 {main}
```

Comment: What does it say in your Laravel log file? There should be a stack trace in there. If not, turn on App debug.

Comment: @Erin added the log

Comment: Just out of interest what version of php you running?

Comment: @rchatburn 5.6.21 (cli)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing it to this

```
public function uploadimg(){
            $file = Request::file('file');
      if ($file) {
            //move it to our public folder and rename it to $name
            $file->move('images', 'insert_file_name.'.$file->getClientOriginalExtension());
            echo 'file uploaded!';
            var_dump($file);
        }else{
            echo 'no file, no bueno';
        }
     }
```

also when you go to the network tab on chrome when you upload it what is the response preview on the error?

Comment: same problem! Yes,when I choose,Its coming the preview,preview is done,and a problem is comming!